# There is pointer fast as stack in C? (Without indirections but still heap)

Tags: c, reference

I am creating a decompiler from IL (Compiled C#\VB code). Is there any way to create reference in C?

**Edit:**
I want something faster than pointer like stack. Is there a thing like that?

Comment: Intuitively, it's the _allocation_ that is slower on the heap than on the stack, not the actual use of the variable. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/79936/1025391). You might need to optimize your allocation strategy if this is indeed an issue for you.

Comment: I knew that ,and my decompiler optimize the allocate (About x11.5 faster) and I saw when I use alot of references (That converts to pointer after decomplication) the performance going down.

Comment: then you probably have another problem with your decompiler, that is apparantly not subject of this question?

Comment: @moooeeeep Yeah ,it's taking a little perf. (With alot of dereferencing i get only x8 more perf than C# ,and with stack i can 40x)

Comment: Make this question active again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Stack* and *pointer* are two completely independent concepts.

A reference is just like a pointer, a way to access/pass a variable without copying it. 
On the other hand, stack and heap are two different places where variables live.
The decision whether or not a variable should live on the stack or on the heap is totally independent from the way you pass it around.

- If you need a local variable, with a lifetime automatically coupled to your function scope declare it on the stack. Allocation is fast, but the object is gone when the function scope ends. Taking this into account, you can pass the variable by value or by pointer to other functions.
- If you need a variable that survives the function scope, you need to make it global (or static), or to put the variable dynamically on the heap. Allocation is a bit slower, but once it's there you can use it like the other. You can pass it by value or by pointer then, either. (Bear in mind, that you need to de-allocate dynamically created objects eventually.)

If heap allocation is indeed a performance bottleneck, you should make sure that you use automatic variables (on stack) where possible. Then, do profiling of your allocation patterns. And finally [optimize your allocation strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1995871/1025391).

Comment: C# uses references alot ,then I used pointer ,and without that I can't create GC.

Answer (score 6):

A reference is just a syntactically sugar-coated pointer–a pointer will do just fine.

Comment: There is a way to replace heap with stack and skip the indirection anytime I use that variable\pointer?

Comment: @SuperFile, No. [Note: What a pointer points to can be on the stack or heap. Ditto a reference.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/57492/1025391)

Comment: @moooeeeep I want something faster than pointer like stack. (Opposite of pointer) There is a thing like that? Something that doesn't need indirection.

Comment: @SuperFile I think that a C++ compiler translates references to derefereneced pointers, so there's is no performance gain. Besides, what are you coding that is sensitive to dereferencing?

Comment: @EitanT Yeah ,it's taking a little perf. (With alot of dereferencing i get only x8 more perf ,and with stack i can 40x)

Comment: @EitanT: It's possible that the questioner is talking about something like this: `int i = 0; int &j = i; j = 1;`. Then a sensible compiler will *not* translate the reference `j` to a pointer, it will just use `j` as an alternative name for the same variable that `i` is a name for. Or perhaps the compiler could treat it as a pointer and then the optimizer eliminates the pointer with identical results as if it had never been a pointer in the first place.

Comment: @SteveJessop I was actually referring to variables passed by reference. In your example I agree that no dereferencing is done, but the OP was talking about the C# `ref` keyword, no?

Comment: @EitanT: I'm not certain what the questioner is talking about, I just think it *might* be that, because of this talk of "replacing heap with stack and skip the indirection". It may mean something completely different, but to me it brought to mind that snippet of C++. Which I concede is a language the questioner hasn't mentioned at all :-)

Comment: @SteveJessep Yeah, most of this discussion is just guesswork.

Comment: @EitanT Yeah I meant the reference of C# that it's working like normal variable but reference (Pointer in my decompiler)